# What's the best combination of LaTex writing in Chinese?

Tags: latex, xelatex

someone rcommend the xelatex, but others insist on the latex+CJK, which one is prefer? thanks.

Comment: Please try on tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

I use LaTeX + CJK and it works fine. Make sure your text editor supports unicode, and then add these lines between the `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` lines:

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\newcommand{\zh}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK}}
```

Now you can insert whatever Chinese characters you like into the document by typing `\zh{中文}`

Comment: Why `zh`? Any motivation behind these two letters?

Comment: It's the standard two letter language code for Chinese: https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/langcodes_name.php?iso_639_1=zh