# Chinese fonts in English Document of Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I would like to ask how to write some Chinese characters (simplified) within an English Latex document? I followed some methods suggested online but none of them are working for me. I am using Texworks to compile my document (pdfLatex).

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}
你好吗
\end{CJK}     
\end{document}
```

another method is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138822/whats-the-best-combination-of-latex-writing-in-chinese),

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\newcommand{\zh}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK}}
```

insert whatever Chinese characters you like into the document by typing

```
 \zh{中文}
```

The error I receive is as following when using the method of CJKutf8 with pdfLaTeX mentioned [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chinese#CJKutf8_with_pdfLaTeX),
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:\Users\muhd_\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log
 )
!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file bsmiu30): Font bsmiu30 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Log file is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HvJ8PIZAxJ4WcMVC3jaRGOPmBI77TcvO/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: If I remove the first `\usepackage{CJKutf8}` from your example, it compiles fine for me with pdflatex. What problems do you face with this method? Do you get any error messages? See https://www.overleaf.com/read/trgqnffkdnht for  the working example

Comment: It's not working if I remove the `\usepackage{CJKutf8}` for me. Without removing the `\usepackage{CJKutf8}` line, I get this error; "!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file bsmiu59): Font bsmiu59 at 720 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!"

Comment: If I remove the `\usepackage{CJKutf8}` Line, then I have this error; ! LaTeX Error: Environment CJK undefined.

Comment: Can you please try to compile exactly the document as I have posted in the overleaf link and add the .log file you get to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the log file. Can you try this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419809/36296

Comment: It's working fine now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error in the log file

```
The process terminated due to an access violation.
```

suggests that there are some problems with permissions while trying to create the necessary files to use the font for the Chinese letters.

Based on this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419809/36296 the problem can be fixed by either runing `updmap` from the command line or `Refresh font map files` from within the miktex console (in `user mode`).